# Why are my css changes not being reflected in my browser?

Tags: css, django

So I am noticing that my css changes are not being reflected. They were originally working when I first created the files but I'm not sure what I did because it's not reflecting changes anymore. I did a hard-reload and cleared the cache but still nothing. Like I can literally delete the css file and my badge which I'm trying to edit is still there... it only goes away once I take it off of base.html directly. So what is going on here? I have a static folder in my app, with a css folder and then my css/notification file. I tried doing collectstatic through terminal but that doesn't do anything. Also, I already have my load static tag in my html. And, my css file is indeed loading when I go to inspect element and the changes are showing up within that file but they are not showing up within my browser. Any idea what's going on here? Nothing I do seems to be working!

ps: Changing STATICFILES_DIR to STATICFILES_DIRS doesn't do anything.

**base.html/header**

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="{% static  'css/notification.css' %}" type="text/css" class = "notification"/>
```

**base.html/body**

```
<a class= text-danger  href="{% url 'dating_app:conversations' user.id %}" type="text/css"      class="notification"> 
                            <span>Inbox</span>
                            <span class="badge">{% unread_messages request.user %}</span>
                        </a>
```

**notification.css**

```
.notification {



  text-decoration: none;
  padding:50;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;

}



.notification .badge {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: -25px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: white !important;
  color: white;
}
```

**settings.py**

```
     STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
"/DatingAppCustom/dating_app/static",
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dating_app/media')
```

**settings.py/installed_apps**

```
'django.contrib.staticfiles'
```

**urls project**

```
  urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('dating_app.urls', namespace= 'dating_app')),


] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**edit/ directory **

```
.
├── 11_env
│   ├── bin
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── activate
│   │   ├── activate.csh
│   │   ├── activate.fish
│   │   ├── django-admin
│   │   ├── django-admin.py
│   │   ├── easy_install
│   │   ├── easy_install-3.7
│   │   ├── pip
│   │   ├── pip3
│   │   ├── pip3.7
│   │   ├── python -> python3
│   │   ├── python3 -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
│   │   └── sqlformat
│   ├── include
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── python3.7
│   └── pyvenv.cfg
├── dating_app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── forms.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── tests.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── chat.html
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── media
│   │   └── profile_photo
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20200410_2231.py
│   │   ├── 0003_auto_20200411_2011.py
│   │   ├── 0004_auto_20200413_1930.py
│   │   ├── 0005_auto_20200413_1946.py
│   │   ├── 0006_auto_20200413_2222.py
│   │   ├── 0007_auto_20200422_1947.py
│   │   ├── 0008_auto_20200425_0039.py
│   │   ├── 0009_auto_20200426_1957.py
│   │   ├── 0010_auto_20200426_2005.py
│   │   ├── 0011_auto_20200426_2005.py
│   │   ├── 0012_auto_20200426_2007.py
│   │   ├── 0013_auto_20200427_1846.py
│   │   ├── 0014_auto_20200503_1947.py
│   │   ├── 0015_auto_20200503_2011.py
│   │   ├── 0016_auto_20200511_0104.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── images
│   │   └── js
│   ├── tag.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── dating_app
│   ├── templatetags
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── unread_messages_counter.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── dating_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
└── static
    ├── admin
    │   ├── css
    │   ├── fonts
    │   ├── img
    │   └── js
    ├── css
    │   ├── notification.css
    │   └── style.css
    └── images
        ├── cupids_corner_logo.jpg
        └── matching_cupid.png
```

Comment: Do you mean even if you've deleted static files and then do hard reload your css styles are still shown but the changes are not being reflected?

Comment: Also please show directory tree of your whole project.

Comment: Exactly, that is indeed happening.

Comment: @Hisham___Pak Ok just put my directory up. My notification.css file is in my static folder, in css folder

Comment: Are other styling files working correctly? Is it just this one that is causing error?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try changing this

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
"/DatingAppCustom/dating_app/static",
]
```

to:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "dating_app/static"),
]
```

as recommended in the docs

Comment: doing so gives me an error ERRORS:
?: (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.

Comment: Okay remove STATIC_ROOT

Comment: and yes btw,  the issue is happening with all css files

Comment: ok well that actually did do something. The css that contains my Jumbotron color actually worked and updated. But the one with my badge for message counter didn't.

Comment: Can you explain which one? and what it was supposed to be and what it is currently?

Comment: Ok, so I have 2 css files in my css folder. One for notification.css which basically just have a message counter badge and one for style.css which has more styles. So, in my styles.css, I changed the Jumbotron color and changed the padding on my navbar, both worked. AND I moved my css from notification.css which has my message counter to my styles.css BUT it still didn't update my message counter. So the problem lies with that piece of code... maybe somewhere else something is overriding it?

Comment: I added the code up there, so you can see it. It was working fine before though!

Comment: Even when I delete the code, delete the file even, it's still not reflecting changes

Comment: Do you mean now css files are working, just one change is not being reflected?

Comment: yes, and it used to be being reflected

Comment: So is this the counter `{% unread_messages request.user %}`? if so can i see the logic behind it?

Comment: I suggest you should open a new question now and accept it as an answer as solved your problem otherwise it will get lengthy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213812/discussion-between-rez-and-hisham-pak).